# RavenDB Consistency - WaitForIndexesAfterSaveChanges() / WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow

Tags: ravendb, data-consistency

I am using RavenDB 3.5.
I know that querying entities is not `acid` but loading per ID is.
Apparently writing to DB is also `acid`.
So far so good. 
Now a question: 
I've found some code:

```
  session.Advanced.WaitForIndexesAfterSaveChanges();
                entity = session.Load<T>(id);
                session.Delete(entity);
                session.SaveChanges();
                // Func<T, T> command
                command?.Invoke(entity);
```

what would be the purpose of calling `WaitForIndexesAfterSaveChanges()`  here?
is this because of executing a command?
or is it rather because might depedning/consuming queries are supposed to immediately catch up with those changes made?
if this would be the case, I could remove `WaitForIndexesAfterSaveChanges()` in this code block and just add `WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow()` in the queries, couldn't I?
When would I use `WaitForIndexesAfterSaveChanges()` in the first place if my critical queries are already flagged with `WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow()`?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for this behavior is wanting to wait, in this operation, for the indexes to complete.
A good example why you want to do that is when you create a new item, and the next operation is going to show a list of items. You can use `WaitForIndexesAfterSaveChanges` to wait, during the save, for the indexes to update.